# ubuntu report wrong disk usage on /

Tags: ubuntu-11.10, disk-space

On my ubuntu 11.10, /dev/sda3 (150GB) is mounted on / and /dev/sda1 (80GB) is mounted on /home. My entire disk has 250GB and the system is reporting I am running out of disk space. Here is the output of df -h:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3             149G  141G     0 100% /
udev                  3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 1.6G  860K  1.6G   1% /run
none                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                  3.9G  508K  3.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda1              74G   15G   56G  21% /home
```

Ubuntu disk usage analyzer report the same thing. But this is weird because I believe I never used that much space on /. I also checked every individual directory under / ( exclude /home ), and they don't use that much space:

```
8.8M    bin
4.0K    dev
0       initrd.img
0       initrd.img.old
828M    lib
15M     lib32
4.0K    lib64
4.0K    media
0       proc
9.2M    sbin
0       sys
1.1G    var
108M    boot
18M     etc
4.0K    mnt
40K     root
4.0K    selinux
72K     tmp
0       vmlinuz
0       vmlinuz.old
16K     lost+found
133M    opt
1004K   run
4.0K    srv
5.9G    usr
```

Any one could give me some ideas what is using up the space? Thanks in advance.

Comment: one thing to add is that I turned the ufw log to full, then I noticed some extreme large log files. But I deleted the log files and turned the ufw log to low again. not sure if that's the problem

Comment: Cross posted on Ask Ubuntu - http://askubuntu.com/questions/163350/wrong-disk-usage-report-on

Answer (score 1):

Why did you exclude your home directories from the 'du' output?

You're getting out of space with approx 7G showing remaining because you're a user, and root reserves (by default) 5% of drive space.  This allows root to perform maintenance when the drive is "full".  5% of 149G is ~7.5G.  (This can be changed and checked with **tune2fs**)

**Something** has used the space, and based the output you show, it's obviously in your home directory.

```
du -scm /home/*
```

Will show the usage for each user's home directory, (probably just yours though).

Once in your home directory, try this to get an idea of where the space is:

```
shopt -s dotglob             # makes * include the .dot files/dirs too
du -scm * | sort -n          # gathers the info, sorts so biggest at end of list
```

That will show you what's being used in your home directory.  The *shopt* command is important, as it makes the * (wildcard) include the hidden dot files.  Without it, you wouldn't be shown the hidden files and folders.  (my .kde is approx 350M, mostly because of nepomuk (which I disable file searching after it's done with initial scans) )

Midnight Commander (type **mc** at a prompt) is good to run around the filesystem with to see what's there.   Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to toggle hidden files on and off (there's a menu option too, but this is easier)

Comment: He seems to have /home on a separate partition.

Comment: Doh!  You're right!  My mistake.   He might try running the two commands I gave as root from the root (/) directory.  (shopt + du)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I left the machine running and I came to the office today and found that "df -h" reports a right disk usage now: 
/dev/sda3             149G  8.3G  133G   6% /
I guess the problem is caused by the log files. But as I mentioned, I deleted them then. I don't really know what's going on.

Comment: Weird!  So this is a 'phase-of-the-moon' thing? ...  Let's see, `pom` gives "11% of waning crescent"... so it happens just before the new moon.  {Grin}  Next month?  Good luck.